# c++ - walking on Set (from STL)

Tags: c++, stl, set, sortedlist

I was wondering if walking on Set (from STL) is very costly? I need sorted array and that's the only reason I used Set. Should I create my own sorted list or walking on Set is "ok"?

Comment: Why do not you think about creating a set? It takes time, too

Comment: Cost is relative. Measure, and iff traversing a set is a bottleneck in your program, think about alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not costly (asymptotically). According to C++ standard it's done in linear time because each step takes constant time (amortized).

Although walking through actual sorted array (e.g `std::vector` or plain C array) may be a little bit faster due to lower constant.